# How can I encode an ordinal variable?

Tags: r

With an ordinal variable, I can peform one-hot-encoding to use in statistical models.  I some books I am reading, I see ordinal variables `[a,b,c]` with ordering `a<b<c` encoded as follows

```
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Here, the extra 1 in the rows of the matrix indicate that, for instance, b has an additional effect on a.

Is there a way to code this in R?  For instance, if I had `[b,a,b,b,c]` the encoding would be

```
110
100
110
110
111
```

Comment: See `?ordered` (assuming you mean ordinal values in the usual sense; I'm not familiar with "one hot")

Comment: @Frank, I know how to create an ordinal variable.  I'm asking how to encode the model matrix for an ordinal variable in the way I've shown.

Comment: I think encode is probably not the right word, but the ordinal package may have what you want.

Comment: You could just fill the lower triangle `mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- 1` after getting an identity matrix. Not sure if that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @markdly's answer, but extended to be subset by the original factor:

```
x <- factor(letters[c(2,1,2,2,3)])
tmp <- diag(nlevels(x))
tmp[lower.tri(tmp)] <- 1
tmp[x,]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    0
#[2,]    1    0    0
#[3,]    1    1    0
#[4,]    1    1    0
#[5,]    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** This answer refers to an earlier [version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45807219/2) of the question. The answer by [thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45807657/8475145) is more up to date.

~~~

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do.  Is this what you are after?

```r
n <- 3
abc <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n) 
abc[lower.tri(abc, diag = TRUE)] <- 1
abc
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    0    0
#> [2,]    1    1    0
#> [3,]    1    1    1
```